# Installing Robot Framework on MacOS - Python Issue

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, anaconda3

Initially, I already had Python 3.8, Pycharm 2020 CE, and Anaconda 3 installed on my Macbook from years before.

I followed a tutorial on installing the Robot Framework, but have run into some issues.

1. I already had the above installed.
2. I, then, installed the Robot Framework and the Selenium library using the below commands via the Terminal application:
   pip3 install robotframework
   pip3 install robotframework-seleniumlibrary

Some errors occurred, so I decide to completely delete Python, Pycharm, and Anaconda from my MacBook by just moving the application to the trash and then emptying the trash, and start over.

So, I:

1. Downloaded and installed Python 3.11
2. Downloaded and installed Pycharm 2023 CE
3. Installed the Robot Framework and Selenium library again
4. Installed Intellibot

This time around, I realized that I did not have a .bash_profile file. So I used "touch .bash_profile" to create the file in the home directory.

Then according to the tutorial, I added the below to the .bash_profile file:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.11
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Browser Drivers
PATH="/Users/leonlin/Documents/BrowserDrivers:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I then closed Terminal and restarted. Then I typed "echo $PATH", and get the below output:

```
/Users/leonlin/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

Now this is VERY different from what the tutorial had (although the tutorial was made 4 years ago). I see all this cryptex stuff, and especially the /opt/anaconda3. I removed Anaconda, so why is the $PATH still showing this? How do I edit the $PATH so there anaconda3 is gone? I have no clue where I am going wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

I was hoping to get something as clean as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq2S2.png)

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1674450/path-still-affected-by-anaconda-after-uninstalling). Exact same issue.

Comment: Worth pointing out is that if you are on decently new-ish MacOS (Catalina or newer) -- Bash wont be your default shell unless you have explicitly set it to bash and thus, adding/changing .bash* files wont be of much use. This is probably why your PATH is what it is...

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the file `/etc/paths` and possibly remove an entry for anaconda.
Add the path to `robot` executable there.

Comment: This is what my /etc/paths file looks like:  
/usr/local/bin 
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin 
/usr/bin 
/bin 
/usr/sbin 
/sbin